# Why does `launch_test` result show "Ran 0 tests in 0.000 s" after running a test?

Tags: ros, ros2, launch-file, unit-testing

I am not the original poster, but I would like to continue the discussion about [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/416762/why-does-launch_test-result-show-ran-0-tests-in-0000-s-after-running-a-test/) asked on answers.ros.org.

> I am trying to write an integration test to test the ROS API of a node I am working on, and I followed some of the examples from the launch and launch_ros repos that use the launch_test tool.
>
> The final output shows that 0 tests ran though, even though earlier up in the output I can see that it ran my test and it shows "Ran 1 test in 7.600s".
>
> Is there any way to stop it from printing "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" at the end? And is there any way to get a cleaner output from launch_test that only shows the test result and not all the logging output from the test?

In the original question, a sample test file is provided but I think that it only adds noise to the issue, and is not really relevant because I noticed this issue on all of my tests and whatever I do it is not going away.